# Sort numpy array on two columns without altering the result of the first

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, matrix

I have an array

```
A = np.array([[   1. ,   -1. ,     0.],
              [  50. ,   10. ,    0.],
              [  10. ,   10. ,    2.],
              [-110. ,   -1. ,     1.],
              [ 120. ,   10. ,     1.],
              [-150. ,   -1. ,     2.]])
```

which I would like to sort **FIRST** in descending order based on the second column and **THEN** in ascending order based on the third column **without altering the result from the sorting of the second column**. So my result should look like:

```
array([[  50. ,   10. ,     0.],
       [ 120. ,   10. ,     1.],
       [  10. ,   10. ,     2.],
       [   1. ,   -1. ,     0.],
       [-110. ,   -1. ,     1.],
       [-150. ,   -1. ,     2.]])
```

This is what I could do best but this alters the sorting done on the second column:

```
ind = np.lexsort((-A[:,1],A[:,2]))
A = A[ind]
```

which produces the following:

```
array([[  50.,   10.,    0.],
       [   1.,   -1.,    0.],
       [ 120.,   10.,    1.],
       [-110.,   -1.,    1.],
       [  10.,   10.,    2.],
       [-150.,   -1.,    2.]])
```

Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's built-in `sorted` for this:

```
A = np.array(sorted(A, key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[2]), reverse=True))
```

By negating the second sorting characteristic (x[2]) and setting reverse to True, it will sort first the second column in descending order, then the third in ascending order.